# how to read first line of a file and store them in an array in java?

Tags: java

Hello guys i have a problem trying to put the first line into an array of 10 intergers. Here is what i have so far

```
public class KnapEncrypt {

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    File file = new File("Testinput.txt");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);

    while(sc.hasNext()){
    int line = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println(line);
    }



 }
}
```

This is the file:

```
191 691 573 337 365 730 651 493 177 354

1000011100

1101000001

0000100010

0100000000

1028

2426

2766

1129
```

Basicaly what I want is putting the first line into an array consist of 10 integers but not the rest of the numbers

Comment: put the first ten you get into an array and ignore the rest.

Comment: Where is your array? You need one to store things in an array. Read the Java tutorial on arrays: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

Comment: This appears as the top google result for 'java scanner first line' which begs the question as to why it is closed / off topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("your_file_here");

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(fis);
    String firstLine = scanner.nextLine();

    firstLine.trim();
    String[] data = firstLine.split(" ");

    int[] intData = new int[data.length];

    for (int i = 0; i < intData.length; i++) {
        intData[i] = Integer.parseInt(data[i]);
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileInputStream(file));
String line = reader.readLine();
String[] lineSplitted = line.split(" ");
```

Answer (score 2):

First read your line from the file:

```
String line = bufferedReaderForFile.readLine();
```

Then hand this to your [scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html):

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(line);
// your while loop here
```